# Branched CNN classifier

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm facing a problem implementing a branched CNN classifier in TensorFlow.

First I have **model1** that has 3 classes **(A, B & C)**
Then **model2** that works on class C that will be classified to **(C1&C2)**

Can anyone help me please, if this is possible or not?

**Code Samples**

Importing the data

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function= \
    tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input)

train_batches = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                            target_size=(image_size,image_size),
                                            batch_size=train_batch_size)

valid_batches = datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                            target_size=(image_size,image_size),
                                            batch_size=val_batch_size)

# Note: shuffle=False causes the test dataset to not be shuffled
test_batches = datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                            target_size=(image_size,image_size),
                                            batch_size=1,
                                            shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Not clear what you need. If I understand you want model 1 to classify a dataset into either class A,B or C. Then you want to take those samples classified as class C and use them as input to model2. If that correct? Also how is your data set input into model1? Is the data set organized as sub directories, one for each class?

Comment: Yes .. exactly!

Comment: please see update to my comment. I can help you but need further information as to data set structure etc

Comment: also do you use generators to provide the data to the model? For example the Image_Data_Generator?

Comment: The dataset is organized as follow:
2 folders one for training data and the other for validation
Then each one of these folders has a sub directory for each class

Comment: I've already implemented the two CNN models .. but each in a separate notebook
and different dataset directory

Comment: how do you read in the data to provide it to the model to train. Please show this code. I assume the validation set is the test set you want to classify as A, B or C then process the one classified as C with your second model which has already been trained to classify C class samples into C1 and C2 is that correct

Comment: Please check my question .. I added the code 

what you're asking is correct **but** the second model is different from that classifies (A, B &C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I can help you but I am still confused. Your test_batches are the same as your valid batches which are already partitioned into A, B and C classes. So why are you using them for test? I would think you would have a separate directory for the test files. If your model is an accurate classifier the predictions on the test set will be closely matched to the classification you made in creating the validation set. Yes there may be some differences due to classification errors and perhaps that is what you are looking to detect.. But OK  see code below. I did not test it but it should do what you want . It will determine which test files were classified as classC. Then it stores those files to a directory you define. Then you can use the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to provide the files as input to model2.predict.

```
c_file_list=[]
class_dict=test_batches.class_indices # dictionary of the form {string of class name: integer indicating class index}
c_index=class_dict['C']  # assumes in the valid directory class subdirectories are named as A,B,C get index for class C
# somewhere in your code you do preds= model1.predict on the test batches
test_file_names=test_batches.filenames # list of file names in the order in which they were processed
for i, p in enumerate (preds): # iterate through the predictions
    pred_index=np.argmax(p) #find the index with the highest probability
    if pred_index==c_index:
        c_file_list.append(test_file_names[i])  # store the file names of all files classified as class C
# now we have some choices in this case I will assume you want to save the files classified as C to
# a directory. Lets call it 'c:\temp\c_classified'    name it as you wish
save_path=r'c:\temp\c_classified'
if os.path.isdir (save_path)==False:
    os.mkdir(save_path) #if the directory does not exist create it
test_list=os.listdir(valid_path) #get a list of files in the valid directory
for klass in test_list:
    klass_path=os.path.join(valid_path, klass)
    klass_list=os.listdir(klass_path)
    for f in klass_list:
        f_path=os.path.join(klass_path,f)        
        test_file_name=os.path.join(klass, f)        
        if test_file_name in c_file_list: #if the filenames matches one in the c_file_list the file was classified as class C
            tfn=os.path.basename(test_file_name)
            dest_path=os.path.join(save_path, tfn) #define the path to save the file to            
            shutil.copy (f_path, dest_path) #copy the file to the save_dir
# Now you can use the files in this directory as input to model2.predict.
```